# Android background process check

Tags: java, android, multithreading, background, process

In my Android application, I want to run some form of a background process, which checks a few conditions every 10 minutes.  If a condition is satisfied, I want to show an AlertDialog box or some form of notification to the user.

How can I do this?  Can anyone provide some source code as a reference point?

I have tried running a new Thread in the Activity onCreate() method, but wasn't able to get too far with that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) with [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html), to call it every X minutes.

The reasons I would suggest that, and not using a background thread that sleeps for 10 minutes each time, are two:

1. You are wasting resources.
2. The android platform already supply you with great services, why not using them?

Answer (score 0):

Create your own Service that has a background thread that loops for 10 mins, this way you can have all your other complicated logic run in this service.

You might find this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) helpful.

I think you will face a problem when you try to create a dialog from a background service, as dialog box can not be created from a Service's context.

A solution will be to have an activity launched in the dialog theme via an intent.